# Reference to a basic style from another ResourceDictionary not found

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have this custom control with my own logic

```
     public class BackButton : Button
{
    public BackButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Button);
        this.Click += (s, e) => { 
            Services.NavigationService.GoBack(); 
        };
    }
}
```

I want to apply to it the default style BackButtonStyle. I do not want to edit StandardStyles.xaml so it's in another ResourceDictionary

```
 <Style TargetType="controls:BackButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
```

Referenced in App.xaml

```
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/FrameworkStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

It is building but this exception is thrown :

```
 Message = "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key BackButtonStyle [Line: 15 Position: 44]"
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`BackButtonStyle` has target type as `Button`, so you can't use `BackButtonStyle` as base style for target type of `controls:BackButton.`

```
<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
```